# How to import library in Java

Tags: java

I just found [project in the Internet](https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/tree/master/webcam-capture-examples/webcam-capture-qrcode) which I need to compile and understand how I can use those libraries;
But I just don't know how to compile it, because I don't understand how to include required libs.

I'm coding on Java just for three days, and I don't even understand how to include my own .java files to work together. (I was invoking bar() method from another Foo.java file like Foo.bar()).

I need somebody to tell me, or just give me a link to any quick guide how to do this without any additional soft (e.g. IDE). Just javac and java commands.

Comment: The libraries are essentially provided for you via Maven.  You should want to start there; get Maven installed locally.

Comment: Does the library consist of `.java` files or a `.jar`?

Comment: The following tutorial should help you: [Classes and Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/)

Comment: I left link to project I need. I don't want use Maven. I just need to finish my project, I have no time to learn everything right now. All I have to use notepad and terminal with javac and java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are biting off a large piece here for someone that is just starting out.

After you make sure you know what a "package" is, you then need to understand the relationship between java packages and the directory structure of java source, class, and jar files; after that, we can introduce the concept of a "classpath". To attempt to short circuit that, I will attempt to tell you how to use these libraries by rote, so to speak, but it is difficult to tell how many things need to be explained when we can't talk about it. But I'll try.

https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture/blob/master/README.md contains a link to a zip file that purports to have all the necessary libraries in it for the project you mentioned. Can I assume you know what a Zip file is and how to expand one? You should download this one, then extract the jar file from its root and the two jar files in its `lib` directory. Put all three of those files in the directory where you intend to do execute javac.

In order to use a class from one of these (presumably you'll only be using classes from the webcam-capture jar), you'll need to know the package that file is in. For instance, the Webcam class is in com.github.sarxos, so to use that class, you would include the line

```
import com.github.sarxos.Webcam;
```

near the top of your own source file. Then you are allowed to use `Webcam` in your source, and the compiler will know that you mean the Webcam class in that package.

In order to compile this, you have to let the compiler know where to find the class files. The compile line would look something like this:

```
javac -cp .;webcam-capture-0.3.10.jar;bridj-0.6.2.jar;slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar MyClass.java
```

(This is Windows syntax; if you're on an *nix system, you use ":" instead of ";".) We are assuming MyClass is in the "default" package; if it is in some other package, you must put its package qualification in as well as its name. You can not set your default directory down to where the source file is and skip entering the package name, you need to compile it from the "root" of your package names. This, incidentally, will not only compile MyClass but all classes MyClass refers to. Assuming it is the 'main' class in a java application, and that you don't do anything fancy about instantiating files with Class.forName(), this javac command will compile all the classes necessary for your program.

Once you get it to compile without errors, you can run it with the same classpath string:

```
java -cp .;webcam-capture-0.3.10.jar;bridj-0.6.2.jar;slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar MyClass
```

So this covers at least two meanings of "including a library"; it gives you an example of telling the compiler and then the runtime where to find the class files in a (jar) library, and I mentioned the "import" statement which, though not required, is standard practice for referring to other classes whether they're in a library or in your own code.

Good luck.

Comment: java -cp .:webcam-capture-0.3.10.jar:core-3.3.0.jar:javase-3.3.0.jar WebcamQRCodeExample
Error: Could not find or load main class WebcamQRCodeExample

Comment: I compiled it without any error. I still can not run it.

Comment: You need to provide more detail in your questions. Is the Webcam... class in a package? Does it have a method with the signature `public void main(String[] arguments)` ? Is it still giving "cannot find or load main class", or did it change error messages between your two comments?

Comment: Once we go back and forth in comments for a little while, SO will suggest we go to a chat room, where the back and forth will be easier...

Comment: I don't know how to create a personal chat room until we go for whatever SO considers "too many" comments and invites us to create one.

Comment: I compiled file which I gave in my question. It is example of a program, which uses libs I need in my project. All .jar libs I downloaded from links leaved in zxing and webcam-capture projects.

Comment: I have noticed that it offers to continue discussion in chat, but I can not start it due to my low reputation. If you can help me I can give u my contacts.

Comment: I found this, but in general it is customary to post what is needed, rather than making people who are trying to help you look stuff up. The file you are attempting to run has a package statement ("package com.github.sarxos.webcam"); do you have a directory for each element of that package?

Comment: There is a "java" chatroom; can you get to that?

Comment: ls .
core-3.3.0.jar    webcam-capture-0.3.10.jar  WebcamQRCodeExample.java
javase-3.3.0.jar  WebcamQRCodeExample.class

Comment: Yes, I have the example code now, I did find it. Or is that not what you're asking? Can you get to the Java chatroom on chat.stackoverflow.com ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129130/discussion-between-0573fe491ea798fdcbc849b0e06edc-and-arcy).

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this.

The simplest way (though certainly NOT the best way!) as follows:

1. Find the ZIP or JAR file containing the precompiled classes.  Hint: look here ... https://github.com/sarxos/webcam-capture .
2. Download it.
3. Figure out what the absolute pathname of the file is.
4. Add the absolute pathname to the CLASSPATH you are using to compile and run; e.g. if you are currently trying to compile from the current directory:

   ```
     javac -cp .:/path/to/library.jar filename ...
     java -cp .:/path/to/library.jar classname args ...
   ```

   For Windows, use Windows pathnames, and use `;` instead of `:` as the classpath separator.

In this particular case, the "binary distribution" ZIP file contains the compiled classes in a nested JAR file.  Also, in the ZIP file's `lib` directory there are a couple of dependent JAR files.  So you need to unpack the ZIP file and add each of the JAR files to the classpath as above.  (You might want to read the documentation links above to find out how classpath wildcards work ...)

I assume that you know how to add the relevant imports to your source code.

---

That is the simple way.  The best way is to install Maven and set your project up as a maven project, and then add a dependency to the library.  Once you have done that, Maven will automatically take care of the downloading, dependencies, the classpath, etcetera.

Java IDEs typically have fair-to-good integration for Maven.  Eclipse's integration is a bit "ropey" IMO, because Eclipse and Maven have conflicting models of certain things.  But it works well enough.  I can't talk from experience about other IDEs.

Comment: The 'library.zip' you mention here won't work on a classpath unless it is organized the same way a jar file would be organized; if, for instance, it contains a "classes" directory in it with the compiled class files below that, then putting this zip on a classpath won't work.

Answer (score 0):

The project has a `pom.xml`. This means that it uses Maven (a build and dependency management tool). [Try to follow this guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven), and install maven on your system.

Run `mvn --version` on console, to check if maven installed correctly. Then navigate to your project folder, and run `mvn`. This will automatically download all the required dependencies (i.e. third party libraries).

Again, if you're not using any IDE, you'll probably need to copy those libs from your system's local maven repo to your project folder (to include them in the classpath). You may wanna read about the classpath more.

Then try to run your file.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need to compile the project:

- Download or clone the project from GitHub
- Install Maven (https://maven.apache.org/install.html)
- From the root directory of the project, where the pom.xml is located run `mvn compile`
- This will download all the libraries required and compile the project.